# Do business pages have user ID numbers?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I created a business page only and am the administrator. Everything that I have read telling me how to find my user id# leads me to the page number. Do business pages have user id#s? If so how do I find it?  I need it for the fb:admins content. Please, I have been trying to figure this out for days and my head is physically spinning.

Answer (score 1):

To find the PAGE id, just do the following. `http://graph.facebook.com/YourPageNameHere`. If you don't have a page name yet (less than X number of fans), then user the # in the link to your page instead of the page name.

example for Coca Cola corp: http://graph.facebook.com/CocaCola

```
{
   "id": "40796308305",
   "name": "Coca-Cola",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276879_40796308305_1578420141_s.jpg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
   "likes": 36645415,
   "category": "Food/beverages",
   "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
   "username": "coca-cola",
   "founded": "1886",
   "description": "On May 8, 2011, Coca-Cola marked its 125th anniversary. Created in 1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. \n\nCoca-Cola was patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States. \n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.",
   "can_post": true,
   "checkins": 77,
   "talking_about_count": 215181
}
```

example for GoDaddy.com: http://graph.facebook.com/GoDaddy

```
{
   "id": "8749090685",
   "name": "GoDaddy.com",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276455_8749090685_6602072_s.jpg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/GoDaddy",
   "likes": 107451,
   "category": "Internet/software",
   "website": "http://GoDaddy.com/ http://twitter.com/GoDaddy http://youtube.com/GoDaddy http://www.linkedin.com/companies/godaddy.com ",
   "username": "GoDaddy",
   "company_overview": "Go Daddy helps people and businesses create and grow their online presence. Go Daddy is the world's dominant domain registrar, is also the top hosting provider in North America and the world's #1 provider of new SSL certificates. Go Daddy develops most all of its 52+ product offerings. Go Daddy has more than 7 million active customers worldwide and provides 24/7 industry-best customer service. The company is U.S. based and doesn't outsource or off-shore a single job.",
   "products": "http://GoDaddy.com/Domains\nhttp://GoDaddy.com/Hosting\nhttp://GoDaddy.com/Email\nhttp://GoDaddy.com/SSL",
   "can_post": true,
   "talking_about_count": 2727
}
```

However, an fd:admin should be a USER id, not a PAGE id.  You can use the graph API explorer to find out your USER id.  Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I have tried that and get 223665414363346 as my ID#.  When I use this as the content for <meta property="fb:admins" content="223665414363346" /> I get the error code "id# for property'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid" when I debugg my web site home page in the Linter.  I also get an error code below the comment box "warning: stonewallplates.com/index.html is unreachable.  I currently have removed this value from content until I get this figured out.

Comment: Oh, fb:admins should your user id and not a page id.  Again, go to the graph and search for yourself.

Comment: I have done that, many times, and keep getting the same #.  I have done it with other accounts to compare with and still believe I am doing it right.  Did it again, get the same #.  Went to CocaCola's page and checked their profile photo for their user id#, did this with my FB page profile photo and again get 223665414363346.  Would you please, please run this through the graph and see what you think?  I have spent well over 10 hours on this and can't figure it out, and FB's help is sparse at best on user id#'s.

Comment: Ran out of space so here's the rest of it.  My Facebook page is http://www.facebook.com/pages/Columbia-Gorge-Stoneworks-Inc/223665414363346 for reference.

Comment: as you can see what you're calling "user" id is not a user id, that id is a PAGE id.  {
   "id": "223665414363346",
   "name": "Columbia Gorge Stoneworks, Inc.",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/372952_223665414363346_1644584594_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Columbia-Gorge-Stoneworks-Inc/223665414363346",
   "category": "Home improvement",
   "website": "www.stonewallplates.com",
   "location": {
      "city": "Lyle",
      "state": "WA",
      "country": "United States",
      "zip": "98635"
   },
   "phone": "509-365-4646",
   "can_post": true
}

Comment: Thank you!!!  I joined Facebook by creating a page for my business.  Do I not have a user id since the page id is all that I can find?

Comment: Hmmm, I've never heard of joining facebook using a business page.  I've always understood the process to be: 1) A facebook user is created. 2) That user creates a facebook page.  How did you skip directly to step 2 without ever creating a facebook user?

Comment: When I log in my business page is what comes up and I can't find a way to any other account.  When I hover over the adminis it just shows my email address.  What am I missing?

Comment: Just went back to figure out what I did 2 months ago.  Instead of logging in to Facebook go to the bottom and select "create page", "company, organization, or institution", and create an account.

Comment: I love learning something new!  Thanks for getting into the time-machine and figuring that out for me :)    I'm really not sure what to suggest if you don't have a user id for an fb:admin.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I guess I need to see if I can create a user account after the page.